# Windows context menu items not showing until hover

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, context

I have a strange bug. Windows 10 context menus (on desktop and in apps) is white and not showing until I hover over it.

Video: https://i.imgur.com/PvG6tMy.gifv

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc I'll try and told you

Comment: @harrymc I boot in Safe mode, and everything working correctly. After that I restart PC in normal mode and everything working well :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, weird, weird. 
It seems the reboot of Windows in Safe mode has fixed the problem.

Apparently, some pending action became possible in Safe mode and the problem
disappeared.
We may never know the reason why it worked, but this post might help others.

Comment: I usually see issues like this when a computer has been on for months or has been using too many resources. A simple reboot has always resolved it for me in the past.

Comment: You are right :)